# Is it possible to limit the cores for Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm using a `Parallel.ForEach` in my code. All my 8 cores go to 100%. This is bad for the other apps that are running on the server. **Is it possible to limit execution to like 4 cores?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the cores to use in Parallelism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956670/setting-the-cores-to-use-in-parallelism)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Pass an instance of `ParallelOptions` with `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set to 4 to `Parallel.ForEach`.

Nevertheless this might not make sense on other machines, that might have more or less cores than you. In general you should let the framework decide the degree of parallelism.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542213/how-to-find-the-number-of-cpu-cores-via-net-c

Comment: @Kees: No, adjusting thread priorities is usually not a good idea. And Tasks are not threads...

Answer (score 27):

You can pass in a [`ParallelOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.aspx) with the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) property set to 4.

Comment: Not a good idea to hard-code that '4'. `Environment.ProcessorCount/2` would do better.

Comment: @Henk: That's hard-coding the 2 :) I was answering the question as asked... exactly how the OP works out how many cores they want is outside the scope, somewhat. (For example, you *may* want it to go flat-out.)

Comment: `Environment.ProcessorCount` returns the number of logical processors, not cores. This is not what Kees needs. For determining the number of cores see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542213/how-to-find-the-number-of-cpu-cores-via-net-c

Comment: @all I won't hard-code the number or cores ;-). Looks like a perfect configuration setting.

Comment: @FlorianGreinacher: Actually the number of logical processors *is* what he would want...

Comment: @Henk: That will run into issues on a single-core machine :)

Answer (score 15):

Here is some code for those who are not satisfied with the other answers

```
List<int> iList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions opt = new System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions();
opt.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4; // << here the maximum of 4 cores

System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<int>(iList, opt, i =>
{
    // do someting with parallelism 4
    Console.WriteLine(i);
});
```