# Thread Limitation for Parallel.For?

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0

My question is is there any way that we can limit the number of threads when we use the Parallel.For loop.

Suppose my machine has I3 processor and capable running 4 processes at a time. so when i run the Parallel.For loop in my machine, there will be 4 threads running in the background.

Is there any way to limit the number of threads?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512312/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-cores-for-parallel-foreach

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114317/does-parallel-foreach-limits-the-number-of-active-threads

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ParallelOptions` with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4`

```
 Parallel.ForEach(words, 
                  new ParallelOptions {
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
                        }, 
                  s => DoAction(s));
```