# Is there a way to fix the number of threads tasks will schedule to run on?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Say I create 3 threads, but wish to run 4 Tasks on them. Is there any way to fix the number of threads that tasks will run on? Thanks.

Comment: Um, what? Each thread will run the code you create it to run. Are you using some particular task scheduling system that you'd like help with? If so, please mention it in your question or in a tag.

Comment: Is this about TPL Tasks?

Comment: @Derwin: this question is still very short on details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the cores to use in Parallelism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956670/setting-the-cores-to-use-in-parallelism)

Answer (score 1):

When you use Tasks (TPL), you do not create the Threads.

Almost every method in the Parallel class will allow you to specify `WithDegreeOfParallelism(n)`

For details, see [Setting the cores to use in Parallelism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2956670/60761)

Answer (score 1):

You could also create your own `TaskScheduler`... *if* you really need to.  Not sure what your particular use case is for it though from your question.  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx) link on MSDN for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In TPL you don't create Threads, you only create Tasks and if you are using the de default scheduler it will use the Threadpool in the back end, and the max number of threads by default is 2*number of cores.
You could create your own custom sccheduler by driving from TaskScheduler if you ant to manage threads creation, this MSDN page shows how to implement custom scheduler that limits the concurrency degree http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx